# Does Elasticsearch have a Default Sort Order for Filter Queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does Elasticsearch have a defined default sort order for `filter` queries if none is specified? Or is it more like an RDBMS without an `order by` - i.e. nothing is guaranteed?

From my experiments I appear to be getting my documents back in order of their `id` - which is exactly what I want - I am just wondering if this can be relied on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you only have filters (i.e. no scoring) and no explicit sort clause, then the documents are returned in **index order**, i.e. implicitly sorted by the special field named `_doc`.

Index order simply means the sequential order in which the documents have been indexed.

If your `id` is sequential and you've indexed your documents in the same order as your `id`, then what you observe is correct, but it might not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

No, the order cannot be relied on (in ES 7.12.1 at least)!

I've tested in a production environment, where we have a cluster with multiple shards and replicas and even running the simplest query like this returns results in different order on every few requests:

```
POST /my_index/_search
```

One way to ensure the same order is to add order by `_id`, which seems to bring a small performance hit with it.

---

Also, I know it's not related to this question, but keep in mind that if you **do** have scoring in your query and you still get random results, even after adding an order by `_id`, the problem is that the scores are randomly generated in a cluster environment. This problem can be solved with adding a parameter to you query:

```
POST /my_index/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
```

More info and possible solutions can be found here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/consistent-scoring.html